# MVT inequality problem

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I just sat a real analysis exam and this was a question in it that I couldn't answer...

Prove that $\left|e^\frac{-x^2}{2t}-e^\frac{-y^2}{2t}\right| \leq \frac{|x-y|}{t}$ for $x,y \in [-1,1] ,t>0$

I ended up trying to set $f(x,y)=e^\frac{-x^2}{2t}-e^\frac{-y^2}{2t}$, then attempted trying $f(-1,-1) =f(1,1)$ but never ended up getting anywhere.

Any tips on how this is actually solved? I've never seen an inequality problem like this before.

Comment: The statement isn't true as written - take $x = y = t = 1$. Did you intend to omit the negative sign in front of the first term, maybe?

Comment: +1 on the above. I assume in the $|\ |$, the first minus sign is mistakenly typed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Observe that, by the mean value theorem,
$$
|e^a - e^b| \leq |a-b|,
\qquad \forall a,b \leq 0.
$$
Hence, if $x,y\in [-1,1]$,
$$
\left|
e^{-x^2/2t} - e^{-y^2/2t} 
\right| \leq
\left|
{x^2/2t} - {y^2/2t} 
\right| \leq
|x+y| \, \frac{|x-y|}{2t} \leq \frac{|x-y|}{t}\,.
$$

Answer (score 2):

You can write when $|x| \leqslant |y|$ and using triangle inequality for integrals :

\begin{align*}
\left|
e^{-x^2/2t} - e^{-y^2/2t} 
\right| = \left| \int_{x}^{y}- \frac{u}{t} e^{-u^2/2t} du\right| &\leqslant \int_{|x|}^{|y|} \frac{|u|}{t} du \\
&\leqslant \int_{|x|}^{|y|} \frac{u}{t} du \\
&= \frac{1}{2t}(y^2 - x^2)\\
&= \frac{1}{2t}(|y| - |x|) (|x|+|y|) \\
& \leqslant  \frac{|y-x|}{t} 
\end{align*}

You can conclude with an argument of symmetry.

Answer (score 0):

Hint. consider $F(z)= \exp(-z^2/2t)\;[|z|\leqslant 1]$, $t$ is fixed. Then MVT.